Receive nothing through ReceiveAsync(Memory<Byte>, SocketFlags, CancellationToken) method
I'm currently studying the TCP receive programming. The problem is while I'm using int reclen = ReceiveAsync(Memory, SocketFlags, CancellationToken) method, reclen > 0 but I just receive nothing in the memory(tcpRecReserve).
    public async Task BeginTcpRecieve()
    {
        try
        {   
            //ArraySegment<byte> bytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(tcpRecReserve,catchNum, tcpRecReserve.Length - catchNum);
            Memory<byte> memory = new Memory<byte>(tcpRecReserve, catchNum, tcpRecReserve.Length - catchNum);
            int reclen = await tcpSocket.ReceiveAsync(memory, SocketFlags.None);
            HandleReceive(reclen);
            await BeginTcpRecieve();
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            print(e.ErrorCode + "/" + e.Message); 
            isConnected= false;
        }
        
    }

Debugging Image1
However, it works well when I switch to ReceiveAsync(ArraySegment, SocketFlags) method.
tcpRecReserve receives  accurate data.
Debugging Image2
My question is why this happened and how can I solve it.

What is the value of reclen? Could it be that it is 0?

why did you ask this again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376258/receive-nothing-through-receiveasyncmemorybyte-socketflags-cancellationtoke - I appreciate you clarifying reclen (the question I'd asked), but: you could have just responded on the original

Debuged again just now, reclen is  precisely 14.  But still  tcpRecReserve is empty as hell.

side note: I would strongly recommend a while loop rather than recursion-to-self, but that won't be causal here - also you need an escape hatch (check reclen against non-positive results); I'm trying to put together a minimal repro; what framework are you targeting here?

Unity 2022.3.15f1c1 c#9.

it's most likely a unity error. i run the same code in my server which is not on unity platform , and everything works all right.

You mention "Unity"; it is possible that this is a Unity error, or it is possible that it is an error in the code you aren't showing, but: here's a slightly modified version of your code (just changed to use a loop rather than recursion) that works fine; output is:
Received: '+PONG
'

which is the expected response from a RESP PING message; code:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program
{
    async static Task Main()
    {
        var client = new Client();
        // connect to a local Garnet server (same API as Redis)
        await client.ConnectAsync(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 3278));
        // note this usage is convenient, but not efficient
        await client.SendAsync("*1\r\n$4\r\nPING\r\n"u8.ToArray());
        await client.BeginTcpRecieve();
    }
}

internal sealed class Client
{
    private Socket tcpSocket;
    private byte[] tcpRecReserve = new byte[1024];
    int catchNum;
    private bool isConnected;

    public async Task ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint)
    {
        tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        await tcpSocket.ConnectAsync(endPoint);
        isConnected = true;
    }

    public Task SendAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> frame)
        =>  tcpSocket.SendAsync(frame).AsTask();

    public async Task BeginTcpRecieve()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //ArraySegment<byte> bytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(tcpRecReserve,catchNum, tcpRecReserve.Length - catchNum);
                Memory<byte> memory = new Memory<byte>(tcpRecReserve, catchNum, tcpRecReserve.Length - catchNum);
                int reclen = await tcpSocket.ReceiveAsync(memory, SocketFlags.None);
                if (reclen <= 0) break; // EOF
                HandleReceive(reclen);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            print(e.ErrorCode + "/" + e.Message);
            isConnected = false;
        }

    }

    private static void print(string v) => Console.WriteLine(v);

    private void HandleReceive(int reclen)
    {
        // TODO: I guess the 0 here should really be catchNum
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: '{Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tcpRecReserve, 0, reclen)}'");
    }

}


BTW I would like to know why while loop is better than recursion in this part. is it to avoid stackoverflow error？Apologies for my ignorance.

@Nocpe partly stack-depth (StackOverflowException), and partly "state machine overhead"; every (there's an asterisk here, but let's not get distracted) time you have an async method, it needs to create a bunch of things to enable that - a locals capture class instance, the Task that will be awaited, continuation/callback delegate, etc; in the while scenario, we create that machinery once, and just keep reusing that single state machine; with the recursive approach you create that machinery every single time

@Nocpe here you go, just for you: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/777cb9fe40879cab69015dc1d7bfaf07
